# Принудительная установка кодировки хранимых процедур MySQL

Tags: mysql, кодировка, stored-procedures

У меня есть несколько дампов MySQL, которые содержат выражения создания хранимых процедур:

```
DELIMITER ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = @saved_sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = @saved_cs_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = @saved_cs_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = @saved_col_connection */ ;
ALTER DATABASE `DB` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
/*!50003 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `GetInfo` */;
ALTER DATABASE `DB` CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_client      = @@character_set_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_results     = @@character_set_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_col_connection = @@collation_connection */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = utf8_general_ci */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_sql_mode       = @@sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' */ ;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`dba`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetInfo`( 
    __id BIGINT,
    )
BEGIN
    SELECT *
  FROM Test
  WHERE id = __id
END ;;
DELIMITER ;
DELIMITER ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = @saved_sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = @saved_cs_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = @saved_cs_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = @saved_col_connection */ ;
ALTER DATABASE `DB` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
/*!50003 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `GetPrice` */;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_client      = @@character_set_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_results     = @@character_set_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_col_connection = @@collation_connection */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = utf8_general_ci */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_sql_mode       = @@sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' */ ;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`dba`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetPrice`(__id BIGINT)
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM Prices WHERE id = __id;
END ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Проблема в том, что перед некоторыми из них принудительно задается кодировка:

```
ALTER DATABASE `DB` CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci ;
```

Можно ли каким-то образом заставить `MySQL` принудительно выставлять кодировку базы в `utf8_general_ci`, вне зависимости от того, что написано перед созданием хранимки? В самом начале дампа и так выставлено, но `MySQL` это не использует при создании хранимок:

```
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `DB` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
```

Answer (score 1):

Эта кодировка была установлена из кодировки подключения в момент компиляции процедуры

Подключитесь к базе с кодировкой utf-8 и перекомпилируйте нужные процедуры

Или удалите из дампа все

```
ALTER DATABASE `DB` CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci ;
```

и перезалейте дамп

Comment: `Подключитесь к базе с кодировкой utf-8 и перекомпилируйте нужные процедуры`, подскажите, как правильно это сделать? Я разные варианты пробовал, ничего не сработало.

Comment: @All_Safe Что Вы пробовали и что не сработало? Подключиться к базе или перекомпилировать процедуры?